# How to put ONLY one image in a multicol column?

Tags: graphics, multicol

I have a multicol section with 3 columns. In the left and middle column, text will be displayed, but the right column shall only contain one image (I have a CV in mind, obviously).
I tried to use wrapfig, but it only gives me the warning "wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment" and puts the image on the next page, leaving the right column blank?

Is there a way to have one multicol column that only contains one image and nothing else? Does it have something to do with the image height?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{flushleft}
    Some very interisting text\\
    Some even more interisting text\\
    \vfill\null
    \columnbreak

    Lorem ipsum \dots\\
    Boring stuff\\
    No one reads this\\
    \vfill\null
    \columnbreak
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.9\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Photo.jpg}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\end{flushleft}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a reason for using a `wrapfigure` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
    \raggedright
    Some very interesting text

    Some even more interesting text

    \vfill\null
    \columnbreak

    Lorem ipsum \dots

    Boring stuff

    No one reads this

    \vfill\null
    \columnbreak

    \raggedleft
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{Photo.jpg}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```